# The value or constructor 'DotCoverNUnit' is not defined

Tags: f#, f#-fake

We're using Fake and I'd like to run DotCover after our Build target. It's alway telling me:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Dev>FAKE\tools\Fake build.fsx

F# Interactive for F# 3.1 (private)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

> [Loading C:\Users\xxxxx\Dev\build.fsx]



build.fsx(8,1): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'DotCoverNUnit' is not defined
```

My short simple "test" script

```ml
#r @"FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake

DotCoverNUnit dotCoverOptions nUnitOptions
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open namespace containing DotCoverNUnit class:

```
 open Fake.DotCover
```

Comment: Yes, that works. Unbelievable I didn't get it. Would you mind to provide a shot working version?

Comment: You can find some samples on FAKE github repository https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/b27c8dc759a824a11389b11b27847bf63066ba79/src/app/FakeLib/DotCover.fs

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get up and running. It didn't display any errors but didn't generate any output either. The FAKE API is lousy for people who aren't familar with F# (like me).

Comment: It is hard to help you when I don't see your code and don't know how you are running it. If you need generic help and series of questions probably f# chat room is a more appropriate place to ask them: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f