# Recursion in F# Example

Tags: recursion, f#

I've started learning F# and following in the footsteps of example problems I've written my own statement. It's simple enough, but I'm getting an error that doesn't exist in similar recursion examples.

My function `replace` takes a `list` of integers, an `swapVal` integer and a `newVal` integer. It then recurses through the list and changes any 'swapVal' to 'newVal'.

```
let original = [1;3;1;4;1;6;1;9]
let rec replace list origVal newVal =
match list with         //look at list

| [] -> []              //when ls empty, return empty list

| head :: tail when head = origVal -> newVal :: replace tail origVal newVal 
//when list is a head attached to a tail, if head = origVal,
//call replace on tail and appead the newVal

|_ :: tail -> replace tail origVal newVal
//head not equal to original value, call replace tail and return result
```

Calling `replace original 1 5` I'm getting the following error `Script.fsx(144,9): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'original' is not defined.` Searching online [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044214/the-value-or-constructor-dotcovernunit-is-not-defined) hasn't turned up any solutions. Even O'Reilly's programming F# says that it could be a scoping problem, but there's no way that scope is my error.

I feel like it could be that f# is typing my arguments incorrectly, but I don't know enough about f# to know how it types. I would cast the arguments to make sure, but I read that it's not possible.

Does anyone see any immediate errors?

Comment: I tried it in F# interactive and am getting `val it : int list = [5; 5; 5; 5]` back.

Comment: Hmm, good to know it's not erroring for you, but it does bring back another problem. I want list to keep every number from the original list EXCEPT the swapped value for the new value .Ideally my code would return [5;3;5;4;5;6;5;9]. Hmmm....

Comment: Also, I'm using Visual Studio Code with ionide f# extension

Comment: In the last case of your pattern match you're basically discarding a value by marking it as `_` and never using again. Change that line to `| t :: tail -> t ::replace tail origVal newVal` and you'll get the expected results.

Comment: I've just tried in VS Code with Ionide and it works fine, with the change I mentioned above.

Comment: I went ahead and created a new f# project and it seems to be working in the new project as well. No idea why it was error in the old project. In your case for the expected results, what does your `| t :: tail` imply? What's `t`? Just some variable name we use for whatever is currently head?

Comment: Just a random variable name. Change with `current` or `head` to be more descriptive. It basically says: *preserve the current value and run `replace` on the rest of the list*. Very similar to the other case where you do an actual replacement. Over there you named the variable `head`.

Comment: OP - You should close this question or edit it so that it reflects your current problem. Sounds like the original problem is no longer an issue.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson what category would I close it under?

Comment: As with most problems, once they have been solved they are no longer an issue, but we don't run around closing every topic that's been solved. To try and close under the "off-topic" makes no sense. I had a question, I gave an example, someone posted a solution. I don't see what merits a close. Feel free to change my mind though, I'm no SO expert.

Comment: I would say either answer it yourself (you can quote people), ask people to write an actual answer, or change the whole question such that it reflects what's actually being discussed.